# Trouble identifying Macromedia Fireworks font

Tags: font-identification, adobe-fireworks

I created the below logo in Macromedia Fireworks and I suspect I may have used one of its fonts.   I no longer have access to the origin file or the software.   I am having a sign made with the logo and I need the name of the font so it can be recreated and vectorized.  I tried to use online font identification at http://www.identifont.com/similar?3NI  but since I only have a few letters to work with as a sample I am not having much success.

Solutions?

[image: logo]

Comment: I have Fireworks CS5, and I just checked and can't find a font like that. Perhaps it shipped with the earlier Macromedia versions, or it was installed on your system at the time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you added the bevel/emboss yourself, I'm pretty sure this is [**Calisto**](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mti/calisto-mt/).

[image]